# Passing a const object in a function

Tags: c++, function, object, constants

I am trying to pass an object into a function, but declare it as const so it can only be read and not changed. An error is being thrown that an expression is required and i'm not sure why or how to fix it.

I have a parent class and its child both with the same function signature, but doing different things and they both need to object to complete their task.

I am still quiet new to c++ and have looked through other questions on this website but not found any answers;

thanks.

```
 class Player{
   char getMove(const Board& board){

     char answer ='a';
     // ...
     return answer;
   }
 };
 class Computer : public Player  {
   char getMove (const Board& board){
      char answer = 'a';
      // ...
      return answer;
   }
 };
```

function calls

```
 int main(){ 

    Player* player[2];
    player[0] = new Player;
    player[1] = new Computer;
    char p0Move, p1Move

    p0Move = player[0]->getMove(const board); 
    p1Move = player[1]->getMove(const board);

 }
```

Errors:
"expression expected" which are at the player[0]->getMove and player[1]->getMove

Comment: What line is this error on; what is it pointing to? Can you make a simplified version of your code where you can show us the *whole* thing?

Comment: Sorry, but you omitted too much. Please read up on how one creates a [mre]. It should be something we can tinker with without needing to fill in any blanks.

Comment: Although... I'd wager that `const board` is the issue. It should probably be `board`.

Comment: Also, unrelated, but you should probably follow standard naming convention and capitalize types (e.g. rename `player` into `Player`)

Comment: Unrelated, but you use dynamic polymorphism without virtual destructor, and probably `getMove` should be virtual too.

Comment: please include the full error message and provide a [mcve], especially `board` is not declared and your `main` as posted here will produce other errors than the one you mention in the question (missing `;` and `Board` not defined). Others can guess, but not providing real code makes it difficult to answer and decreases the chances that this question will be useful to future readers to close to zero

Answer (score 4):

These lines are the problem:

```
p0Move = player[0]->getMove(const board);
p1Move = player[1]->getMove(const board);
```

you don't need the 'const' here. What you want is:

```
p0Move = player[0]->getMove(board);
p1Move = player[1]->getMove(board);
```

Comment: "Reference to type 'const Board' could not bind to an lvalue of type 'Board *'"

it throws the error above, does it have something to do with the board object being declared dynamically?

Comment: That's a type mismatch; you're trying to pass an object of type `Board *` (i.e., pointer to Board) to something that wants a `const Board&`, i.e. a reference to a Board or a reference to a const Board. You need to dereference the pointer to get the actual object.

Comment: Where is board defined, I don't see it in the question

Comment: There's no such thing as *declared dynamically*. An object can be allocated dynamically. I'm not trying to be a pedant, it's just that to gain understanding of C++ you have to get the basic concepts straight.

Comment: I guess by declared dynamically you need declared as a pointer. If that's the case then yes, that's the problem, simple answer is `player[0]->getMove(*board);`, use `*` to dereference the pointer to get the object.

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code in Visual studio 2017:

1) add public Specifier

```
class Player {
public:
    char getMove(const Board& board) {

        char answer = 'a';
        // ...
        return answer;
    }
};

class Computer : public Player {
public:
    char getMove(const Board& board) {
        char answer = 'a';
        // ...
        return answer;
    }
};
```

2. Remove Const

   p0Move = player[0]->getMove( board);

   p1Move = player[1]->getMove( board);

Comment: And ... ? This still does not define board.